# PHP Execute Code AFTER user receives a response

Tags: php, codeigniter, http, curl, asynchronous

I have a api built with PHP & Codeigniter + RestClient and its getting to the point speed matters. We have ALOT of code that the user should really not need to have to wait on to receive a response from the API that I would prefer to be executed AFTER the user receives a api response. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Mind showing a piece of the said code?

Comment: Nothing I show will help in this regard. Im asking how to execute a isolated chunk of code async using php.

Comment: Asynchronously no, you cant. Synchronously yes. Reason being that Async is to run commands/requests/etc without having to wait/rely on other/previous requests.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is possible if your server run PHP as PHP-FPM. See in documentation functions with prefix fastcgi_
2. You can move your "special" code to separate file and run this file as daemon. Not sure about PHP scripts, but for Python scripts this is possible.